# Unity: How to save and load scenes according to player progress

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set up a game in which each time a player completes a level, the next one loads. As the player completes levels, if he completes level 1 level 2 loads and so on.

I have tried using a variable to do this. So that the variable increases and Unity loads the scene corresponding to that variable (1 = level 1, 2 = level 2 and so on). The issue I am having with this is that I want unity to remember said variable, so that when the game loads for the second/third time, the user starts on level 2 not level 1 (or indeed higher)

There is no code for me to provide here, as I am trying something that I don't know how to do

Answer (score 2):

You can save the state of an object to a file by serializing it. Here is a full tutorial on this: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/persistence-saving-and-loading-data

The relevant piece of code is this:

```css
public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float health;
  public float experience;
  
  public void Save()
  {
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat");
    
    PlayerData data = new PlayerData();
    data.health = health;
    data.experience = experience;
    
    bf.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();
  }
  
  public void Load()
  {
    if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat"))
    {
      BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
      FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerInfo.dat", FileMode.Open);
      PlayerData data = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
      file.Close();
      
      health = data.health;
      experience = data.experience;
    }
  }
}

[Serializable]
class PlayerData
{
  public float health;
  public float experience;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PlayerPrefs to store the level value.

eg.
When scene is load you can get level value in Start() method

```
void Start()
{
   //It will return level value, if player is playing game first time default value is return 0
   int level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level", 0);
}
```

Now when player finish current level then you can increase level and store like this.

```
void LevelComplete()
{
  //It will return current level
  int currentLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level", 0);
  // Now we increase one level and store new level
  currentLevel++;
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", currentLevel);
}
```

Comment: You should **not** use the playerprefs for that! Read [here](https://medium.com/@zachcaceres/persistent-data-between-scenes-how-to-use-playerprefs-in-unity-b6fd409363c3) the section **`Careful: Don’t Use PlayerPrefs For Important Stuff`**

Comment: Ah I see. So anyone can go through playerprefs to change the level. Is there a good alternative?

Comment: There is no alternative. 
You should use playerprefs to save progress. 
There are alternatives but when player close the game then progress will lose.

Comment: @DharmeshPrajapati What do you mean no alternative? Unity gives us the very helpful [`Application.persistentDataPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) for exactly this use. This directory should be used to store your game's important save data instead of playerprefs.